# Xcode error "The file MyApp couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it" after switching to a new computer

Tags: xcode

Just switched to a new MacBook after my old one got a logic board issue and died. I transferred some apps over from an external hard drive, and none of them will run-- I just get the error in the title.

This has been addressed before, but none of the solutions have worked. I've tried:

- Manually setting file permissions
- Cleaning the project multiple times
- Setting the compiler for C/C++/Obj C to default
- Restarting my computer
- Replacing my info.plist file with a clean one
- Deleting derived data
- Checked my architecture settings are accurate
- Some other solutions I've found on here (deleting folders that code was moved into, etc) aren't applicable

Worth noting that in addition to switching computers I upgraded Xcode to the latest version (my version on the previous computer was about a year old).

Does anyone have any other thoughts? I'm stuck and have no idea what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try change permissions recursively. Go to terminal, open folder with your project and write:

`sudo chown -R $USER .`